# how can we find group in forceNetwork function of package networkD3?

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to create D3 networks in [r](/questions/tagged/r) using [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package with the function `forceNetwork`, i.e.

```
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

I want to know, on what basis do they make groups.

The sample data in R gives two tables to create a network,

```
1)   MisLink: which gives information about the links
header:   |source |target |value
     1    |  1    |  0    | 1
     2    |  2    |  0    | 8
     3    |  3    |  0    |10
     4    |  3    |  2    | 6
     5    |  4    |  0    | 1

2) MisNode: which consists of information regarding nodes.
header:  |              name| group| size
       1 |          Myriel  |   1  | 15
       2 |        Napoleon  |   1  | 20
       3 | Mlle.Baptistine  |   1  | 23
       4 |    Mme.Magloire  |   1  | 30
       5 |    CountessdeLo  |   1  | 11
```

My Node data doesn't have any  group column. How do I create a GROUP column?

Two tables which I have are as follows:

```
Link Table:

Source |    Target     |  EdgeWt
5-HT1A |    depression |    4
5-HT2A |    depression |    5
5-HT2C |    Anxiety    |    3
5-HT2C |    depression |    4

Node Table:

Id     | NodeType
5-HT1A | GeneSymbol
5-HT2A | GeneSymbol
5-HT2C | GeneSymbol
ACNE   | Disease
ACTA   | GeneSymbol
ACTH   | GeneSymbol
```

I can change the Source and Target to numbers, but in the end I want node colors on the basis of NodeType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your nodes are not grouped, then you can simply add a group column to your Nodes data where the value is the same for every node, like...

```
myLinks$group <- 1
```

If your data is grouped, than add that data to your Nodes data frame and refer to that column name in the `Group` argument.

---

Given your data that you added, this is how it can be achieved (`Group = "NodeType"`)...

```
links <-
  data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    Source = c("5-HT1A", "5-HT2A", "5-HT2C", "5-HT2C"),
    Target = c("depression", "depression", "Anxiety", "depression"),
    EdgeWt = c(4, 5, 3, 4)
  )

nodes <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Id = c("5-HT1A", "5-HT2A", "5-HT2C", "ACNE", "ACTA", "ACTH"),
  NodeType = c(
    "GeneSymbol",
    "GeneSymbol",
    "GeneSymbol",
    "Disease",
    "GeneSymbol",
    "GeneSymbol"
  )
)

nodes <- rbind(nodes, c("depression", "Disease"), c("Anxiety", "Disease"))

links$Source <- match(links$Source, nodes$Id) - 1
links$Target <- match(links$Target, nodes$Id) - 1

library(networkD3)

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
             Source = "Source", Target = "Target",
             Value = "EdgeWt", NodeID = "Id",
             Group = "NodeType", opacityNoHover = 1, 
             opacity = 1, fontSize = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: i am updating the question with kind of data I have, please help me according to it.

Comment: Answer is the same. Add a group column to your nodes data and set it equal to one.

Comment: Though your source and target values in your links data frame are clearly wrong, but that’s a different question/problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew source and target value are supposed to be in numbers. I changed that. And also figured the way out for Groups.

Comment: updated my answer based on the data you added/changed

Comment: Thanks CJ. I will try thisout as well. :)